# DHCP v6 Option for Circuit ID

Tags: dhcp, ipv6

DHCP v4 has Circuit ID option(82:1) for defining the actual interface ID of the Client.

What is the equivalent option in DHCPv6?

Answer (score 2):

Section 22.18 of [RFC3315](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3315.txt) - the DHCPv6 RFC - defines an Interface-Id option (option-code 18) which allows the client to provide interface information to the DHCPv6 server.